# how to setup multi master nodes in hadoop(2 masters and 4 slaves)?

Tags: hadoop, master-slave, redundancy

I am trying setup a hadoop cluster in which i had already setup 1 master and 4 slave.Now I am trying to make redundant master and redundant slaves.
How do i make 2 master (redundant master) and redundant slaves in my cluster?
please help..

Answer (score 1):

You don' need redundant slaves, just add more workers and then re-balance your hdfs cluster.
The hdfs is automatically replicated between workers depending on your block replication settings (default is 3). 
The secondary namenode (master-slave) was improved starting with hadoop 2, i don't know what version you use.
You should definatelly read this http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html

Comment: please, can you give some basic idea about hdfs high availability? that's will be helpful for going in depth.

Comment: HDFS High Availability provides the option of running two redundant NameNodes(master nodes) in the same cluster in an Active/Passive configuration with a hot standby. Prior to Hadoop 2.0 the NameNode(master node) was the single point of failure in a cluster. You only need redundancy for NameNodes, because the Slaves replicate the data between themselves (HDFS block replication) so if one goes down, blocks from it will be available on some other slave. Namenode knows when a slave is down and is able to continue processing data by reading the blocks from another node.